# Debian - problem logging in with main user - gdm? gnome?

Tags: debian, xorg, gdm

I'm using Debian buster/sid.

I updated my system and after a reboot my mains user cannot login through gdm. X is not starting.

I can login through command line. I created a new user and I could login through GDM and start Gnome.

I tried to move / backup all my config, gnome related and XAuthority files from my main user account, but it didn't solve the problem.

I tried to install lightgdm and did a reboot. At this stage the new user I created couldn't login anymore.I created another new user, and it can login fine.

My /var/ partition was full, so I emptied some old logs and cache. I also noticed apache2 and MariaDB could not start either...

I had a look at the Xorg logs but there's no error... any help to debug this appreciated!